# how to set JS Function for the highcharts options

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, gson

I want to set js function for my highchart options. I will generate these options with gson. In gson you can't include js functions in json, so I can't include my js functions from java

```
    $('#container').highcharts({        
        title: {
            text: 'Async drilldown'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Things',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Animals',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: true
            }]
        }],

        drilldown: {
            series: []
        }
});
```

For the above highchart options, I need to set the below js function drilldownfunc for the drilldown event.

```
function drilldownfunc {
    var chart = this,
    drilldowns = {
        'Animals': {
            name: 'Animals',
            data: [
            ['Cows', 2],
            ['Sheep', 3]
            ]
        }
    },
    series = drilldowns[e.point.name];

    chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);

}
```